# Float left div is covering up non-float div on the right

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the right dark square to cover up a little of the big white square, and making the white square a "float: left" almost does this, but the white square is covering up the black square. How do I fix this?

http://strange-coast.com/9thdawn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add this to your sidebar css, the black square will appear on top:

```
position: relative; /* div needs a position */
```

Comment: You, sir, are a hero and a savior. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest of your development ;)

Comment: Do you know why it happens so for static position (which is div default)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="sidebar" style="position:relative; z-index:1;">
```

Comment: Thank you. I gave you a upvote, but liked the CSS answer better cause it's CSS.

Comment: No problem! Just a note: mine is CSS too! It's just inline, but the same CSS! :)